# How do you approve/reject an orphaned suggested edit with no buttons?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I was browsing the suggested edits queue and ran across [a suggestion that had no buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/193043). It's a wiki edit for a tag which appears to no longer exist.

[image: no buttons]

It also doesn't appear to be formatted the same as other tag wiki edits. Normally it would say "[orphan](/questions/tagged/orphan) tag wiki" but this just says "orphan wiki" and links to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9105826/revisions), which is empty.

Comment: A wild guess is that the "recurly" tag was auto-pruned, effectively "orphan"ing the suggested edit...which somehow got conflated with the [tag:orphan] tag (which should probably also die). Weird stuff.

Comment: I nuked it, mention it here when this happens will look at a more comprehensive fix

Comment: @waffles: There are [two](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/208295) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/208296) in the suggested edit queue that need nuked.

Comment: And [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220841) today

Comment: @waffles - [A new challenger appears!](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220889)

Comment: @waffles And [one](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220818) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220890) [three](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/221795) more.

Comment: @waffles http://i.stack.imgur.com/jLeSa.png

Comment: @waffles: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125952/so-suggested-edits-lists-a-number-of-orphan-wiki-entries

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well this is a bit annoying. I changed it so we automatically reject all the suggested edits on orphan wikis. There is no ideal way of acting here, but this will do as orphan wikis are quite rare.

Comment: I think this is a proper action. Some of the ones I've been seeing are just notes "do not use this tag for anything" which isn't a tag wiki anyways and doesn't deserve to be approved, even if the tag did still exist; like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/208295) that Jeff approved for some... reason.

Comment: Could [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126248/suggested-edits-to-tag-wikis-are-systematically-and-silently-rejected) be an unintended consequence?

Answer (score 3):

These appear to be showing up with greater frequency. Could be coincidental - but just a few minutes ago I saw five at the top of the suggested edit queue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220818
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220841
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220889
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/220890
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/221795 - [box.net] tag

Comment: I guess some of those are probably the same as what we've been putting in the comments - that they assaulted me simultaneously as a group in the edit queue kind of made me Eeeek, though.