# Suggested edits to posts which no longer exist should be automatically removed

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

This expands off of [this other question by me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121023/how-do-you-approve-reject-an-orphaned-suggested-edit-with-no-buttons) about orphaned tag wiki edits still existing in the suggested edit queue. Today, I also noticed this edit:

[image: Edit to deleted post]

This edit was made on a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469646/train-perceptron-to-separate-guassian-distributions) which was subsequently **voluntarily removed by its author**. Hence, the Improve button has been removed. Additionally, the [permalink to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/210301) links to a "Page Not Found" which also isn't very useful (does it do that for 10k users too?).

When the post that a suggested edit belongs too gets deleted, so should the suggested edit. The edit gets deleted in all other aspects, since the permalink doesn't even work, but why does it still display in the suggested edit queue?

To tie into the previous issue (linked at the beginning), this should also apply to suggested edits which are made on a tag wiki which is subsequently deleted.

Comment: Deletions are reversible, so whatever mechanism you employ here should be reversible also.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? Also, what exactly should happen to the suggested edit, if the question is deleted while it's still pending? Removed like it was never suggested, or "frozen" until the post is undeleted (undeletion needs to be taken into account) and then again showing up in the review queue?

Comment: @AnneDaunted I'm... not sure. At one point I thought we automatically changed suggested edits to "no longer reviewable" and just silently canceled them when a post was deleted, but I've also seen reports of people continuing to review suggested edits for deleted posts.

Comment: The bug [still continues to exist eight years later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344355/should-i-be-asked-to-review-edits-on-deleted-posts). Any chance of an investigation and potential fix?