# Please don't make us review suggested edits for deleted questions

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested edits to posts which no longer exist should be automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/suggested-edits-to-posts-which-no-longer-exist-should-be-automatically-removed)

I was reviewing suggested edits, and one was for:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228874/moving-a-image-in-java-across-the-screen

I 'improved' the edit.  When I was taken to the 'post improvement' view, I was notified that the question had been deleted by the owner — and that it was done an hour ago.  (I generated the list of suggested edits a minute or two earlier; nowhere near an hour ago.)

When a question is deleted, the outstanding suggested edits should probably be cancelled.  At the least, the 'improve' button should notify that the question has been deleted.

I don't think reviewers should be expected to expend energy on deleted questions.

Comment: Or suggested tag wiki edits for deleted tags...

Comment: I thought they were are *supposed* to be deleted (waffles posted something on a question about it), but they've been having problems with this apparently. Although, normally, the system should remove the Improve button when it knows you can't edit the post anymore... Related: [Suggested edits to posts which no longer exist should be automatically removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/suggested-edits-to-posts-which-no-longer-exist-should-be-automatically-removed)