# Where are "improve / reject and edit" options?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

> [image]

I can't see them anymore. Thats [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32425) suggested edit.

Oh wait, this post was deleted. Why did it appear in the review queue then?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/suggested-edits-to-posts-which-no-longer-exist-should-be-automatically-removed

Comment: So the bug is by design and if you mean this as feature request to change this, it's a dupe. :)

Comment: Huge buttons! You should decrease the zoom level :P

Comment: @Inf Samsung Galaxy S5 has a huge resolution :D

Comment: Great! Then it's a perfect fit for people with fat-fingers and 2222 repz :D

Comment: @Inf I didn't say it has really large screen ;)

Comment: Get a larger screen now! Then you will be able to see the awesome features of SE, rather than seeing only the bugs all the time :P

Comment: @Inf only bugs? U sure? And holes?