# What exactly happens to a suggested edit if the post is removed by the author or for Moderation reasons?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, deleted-answers

[This link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/how-can-i-track-app-usage/115919#115919) will lead to an *spam* answer on Android Enthusiasts (affiliation wasn't disclosed; posted by `user117708`, now nuked!) which is deleted as of now, and only 10k and above reputation points holder would be able to see it.

Before I marked the answer as spam I rejected a Suggested Edit on it because I considered it to be polishing the spam. I also vaguely remember that, before checking my helpful flags to find that the flag was resolved as helpful I was the only one who reviewed that edit.

Now that I neither can find that deleted answer in my review history nor in the Suggestions history of the user who suggested that edit, I'm curious to know what exactly happened to that edit, or what usually happens to such an edit?

- Did other reviewers review it and the edit was resolved as approved/rejected?
- Did a Moderator (a human) review it?
- In case none of the reviewers or the Moderators reviewed it, did Community ♦ jump in and post a predefine message?
- Perhaps a possibility I'm missing here. What would that be?

**Edit**: It is at least clear that not all the Suggested Edits disappear in thin air if the post is removed. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/438760)  is a reviewed Suggested Edit (found it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123660/286110)) for a question which was later voluntarily removed by its author.

Comment: Good question.  I saw the review and either hit Skip or closed the tab shortly before I nuked the user, so it "disappeared" while it was still pending.  I can't find the edit either now....

Comment: @MatthewRead Does such edits on deleted posts are visible to site Moderators, or is it for some other reason you can't find the said edit?  I tried searching similar stuff on other Meta sites using Google but couldn't find anything related. // Anyhow, I checked out my browser history, and I think either [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/99333) or [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/99355) is the link for the edit. Can you please verify them?

Comment: I can't see anything at those links.  It seems like the system completely removed the edit.

Comment: @MatthewRead OK, thanks for the help. I somewhere heard that system always keep the content though it may be away from the reach of users, and is always available to the Developers of [SE]. So should this question be migrated to [meta.se] or should I let go of this issue at all?

Comment: I've migrated since it does seem broadly relevant, and maybe a bug since I am not sure there's a bigger reason to hide the edit just in this case.

Comment: I've hit such edits once or twice; I believe the review queue entry simply becomes invalid immediately and is no longer shown to anyone, but a reviewer that still has it open will of course still see it until they take some action. Only Skip will actually work normally, though; the others give an error message.

Comment: As far as I know, the suggested edit just keep sitting in the queue, but can be accessed only by direct URL, i.e. not given to reviewers in the usual process. I think it was reported once when such zombie edits filled up the whole queue, and a dev just manually nuked them. (going to search for that)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Could you please tell what kind of direct URL for Suggested Edit it is? I'm only aware of [this kind of URL](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/438760) for Suggested Edits.

Comment: @Firelord yes this kind, same like ordinary user (i.e. not moderator) can't find his own deleted old posts, unless he got a direct link.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have 10k on Android.SE and can't comment on what happened on that edit, but generally speaking, those suggested edits stay in the queue. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1173015/suggested-edits-on-deleted-posts) lists quite a few on Stack Overflow, e.g. [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1173015/suggested-edits-on-deleted-posts) where the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59516595/timeline) looks as follows:

- 2019-12-29 03:16:05Z: edit suggested
- 2019-12-29 04:20:17Z: question deleted by author
- 2019-12-29 04:49:31Z: one reviewer approved the edit
- 2019-12-29 07:37:41Z: a second reviewer approved it, so the suggested edit was applied; note that the editor didn't gain reputation because the post was already deleted.

[image]

On the other hand, when a post is deleted as spam, the pending suggested edit is deleted (not just invalidated). I suggested a [test edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjY59.png) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59527610/timeline) which was marked as spam, but the [review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24972666) now 404s.

Comment: It might not have anything to do with the *spam* (or red flag) deletion in particular, but probably just to do with the lock. Can you test what happens to pending suggested edits if the post is later locked?