# Error when reviewing suggested edit on a deleted post from Q&A page

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

A post that, after an edit was suggested, is deleted, still has the "Edit (1)" link in the post menu. When you try to review that suggested edit from the Q&A page, and click 'Approve' in the popup with the review item, you get an error message:

> This post has been deleted; no edit suggestions are available

[image]

That might make sense, but I'm reporting this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because the inconsistency here is that it *is* possible to review the edit from the review queue: [proof](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32064860).

If [Suggested edits to posts which no longer exist should be automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123660/295232) is implemented, then this bug is also fixed, but if it's not (the post can get undeleted later, even *because* the suggested edit might make it worth undeleting), this inconsistency should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I've been aware of this but never thought it was a bug.

While questions might for all purposes disappear after deletion, answers that are deleted under visible questions will still be visible to 10k users so approving a suggested edit will make them more readable for any 10k user who might take interest in a thread's history.

To a lesser degree the same can be said of questions, links to deleted questions might still linger around not just in the OP's posting history but also in the curator's actions history. If someone suggests an edit that objectively makes a post better (and posts can be nearly unreadable) why not let the suggestion/review take its course?

The only possible argument against (that I can think of) could be that 1 or 2 reviews go to waste; but I still think it can make the post histories overall tidier! And lets assume that whoever suggested the edit is likely to have wasted more time than reviewers at no gain in rep after deletion.

So yes, it should be possible to approve the suggested edit both from the review queue and clicking the Edit(1) link under the post.

Comment: Thanks for your insights; I do think they are more appropriate [over there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123660/295232) than under this bug report (but I could be mistaken)?

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm not sure the interface details are the same in Animusson's post, it's been 10 years...