# SO Suggested Edits lists a number of Orphan Wiki entries

Tags: support, orphaned-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you approve/reject an orphaned suggested edit with no buttons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121023/how-do-you-approve-reject-an-orphaned-suggested-edit-with-no-buttons)

Currently, there are a number of 'Orphan Wiki' entries in the suggested edits list on SO.  They're puzzling; there's nothing that people can do to them — no approve, disapprove, improve options.  Some of them are marked as two days old.

What's supposed to happen them?

Comment: [This has happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121023/how-do-you-approve-reject-an-orphaned-suggested-edit-with-no-buttons), so maybe it's time to consider that "more comprehensive fix".