# Suggested edits to tag wikis are systematically and silently rejected

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I just submitted a few suggested edits to tag wikis on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), ([137](https://cs.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/137)–[146](https://cs.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/146)). All of them were newly created excerpts or wikis. They have been rejected silently: there is no indication of who did the rejection, not even Community. None of the users in the CS chat saw the edits, though one reports [“I did see something in my status bar, but they had disappeared before I could look at them”](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3889357#3889357).

To see if this was a site-specific bug, I tried a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/224149) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) to an existing wiki. It was “Pending” for a few seconds, then after reloading the page, it became “Rejected”, again with no explanation.

It looks like suggested edits to tag wikis are silently lost.

Comment: happend to me too: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/223968

Comment: [Happens on Gaming as well](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/3876), but that one was pending for about 20 minutes. If you go through these via the 10k tools, it just says "rejected by 12 hours ago".

Comment: This is strange.  I know I saw suggested tag wiki edits on SO as recently as yesterday, but there are currently none in the queue.

Comment: @BilltheLizard [This change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121023/how-do-you-approve-reject-an-orphaned-suggested-edit-with-no-buttons/126091) may have been a trifle on the eager side. That's one for the devs to figure out.

Comment: I've asked the same thing before and never got a response. I wonder if anyone is there. I've put up descriptions for Paradox, Interbase and ReportBuilder. They were up for days or weeks, then disappeared. Now they go asking for input. Annoys me every time I visit a favorite tag.

Comment: @PatrickMoloney This is a new bug. Are you refering to [your suggested edits on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/688963/patrick-moloney?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)? The three good ones were accepted, and are still there. You've only created excerpts (shown in the popup on the tag buttons), not wiki bodies; if you write wiki bodies, they'll appear where you currently see “help us create it”.

Comment: Reported on [su] as well [Why was my tag suggestion rejected?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/4621)

Comment: Another flag with the same problem: http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/9749

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My bug ... apologies, I am just deploying a fix to correct this retroactively.

It was a side effect of an [incorrect fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126091) I applied earlier this week.

50 tag wikis were affected on Stack Overflow

Comment: "correct retroactively" as in they'll be in the queue again? We had one on Unix and Linux as well

Comment: yes in about 2 minutes and 42 seconds