# New tag wikis cannot be created

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

I just noticed something that might become a problem in the near future.

It's currently impossible to create new tag wikis. Editing existing ones seems to work, but you can't create new ones. The edit links all just redirect to the tag info page. This seems to be the case on every Stack Exchange site.

For example, try creating a tag wiki for the [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox) tag here on MSO. I'll wait.

Comment: [I confirm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129003/unable-to-create-tag-wikis), on all sites (well, I tried 5), at all privilege levels up to moderator.

Comment: I can see it be able to edit the stackexchange tag here.

Comment: @Benny That's not a new tag wiki, [meta-tag:stackexchange] already has an excerpt.

Comment: Also, possibly related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126248/suggested-edits-to-tag-wikis-are-systematically-and-silently-rejected)?

Comment: @lunboks Ah, sorry about that, I mis-read the question

Comment: Similar problem [reported on Programmers.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/why-cant-i-edit-tag-wikis).

Comment: And also on [Gaming.SE](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4500/unable-to-create-new-tag-wiki)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "This post doesn't exist yet" fact confused the "Can this post be edited?" logic here. Fix is being rolled out to the network right now.