# Unable to create tag wikis

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New tag wikis cannot be created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129002/new-tag-wikis-cannot-be-created)

I can't seem to create any new tag wiki. Editing existing wikis works fine (even one that has been created but is currently empty), but creating a new wiki fails. When I visit `http://SITENAME.com/edit-tag-wiki/NUMBER` (e.g. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/687, linked from https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of), or click `Create Tag Wiki` on `http://SITENAME.com/tags/TAGNAME/info`, I'm redirected to the tag info page.

I tried on Scifi, SO, French, CS, Unix, CSTheory, with privileges going from <1000 to moderator. All sites are running rev 2012.4.11.2198. I only tried in Chrome 18.0.1025.142.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129002/new-tag-wikis-cannot-be-created

Comment: @DanielFischer Dammit, FGITW'ed. If I hadn't searched before posting, I'd have been first! Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I wasn't the first one either. Someone [reported it](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4500/unable-to-edit-tag-wiki) on the Gaming Meta an hour ago, but this seems to be an issue on every single site in the network.